Unable to generate concise footcite
In my current document, I want to generate a minimal reference in the footnote. I am using \footcite{} using the biblatex package.
This is the code I am currently using:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}

\bibliography{references.bib}

\begin{document}

This is a sentence with a citation.\footcite{MyCitation}
\end{document}

And the output foot note citation I get is:

I want the output to look like this:

This is the content of the reference.bib file:
@article{MyCitation,
  title = {In Vivo {{Localization Studies}} in the {{Stramenopile Alga Nannochloropsis}} Oceanica},
  author = {Moog, Daniel and Stork, Simone and Reislöhner, Sven and Grosche, Christopher and Maier, Uwe-G.},
  date = {2015},
  journaltitle = {Protist},
  shortjournal = {Protist},
  volume = {166},
  number = {1},
  pages = {161--171},
  issn = {14344610},
  doi = {10.1016/j.protis.2015.01.003},
  url = {https://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S1434461015000048},
  langid = {english}
}

How do I achieve this? I have tried all the various styles in biblatex (chem-acs, nature, etc.), but to no avail. The only thing that works is verbose, but that is too long for my needs.

Would \footfullcite do?
